# Pulseaudio microphone doesn't work

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, microphone

I am using Slackware 14.1. I installed pulse audio. The sound output works fine. But the microphone doesn't work in skype. I tried the steps from here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Inserted into `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,0
```

Then restarted the server:

```
$pulseaudio -k
$pulseaudio -D
```

But still doesn't work. Any clues to fix the issue?